# "Unable to find the mojo Error" At My Custom Maven Plugin

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-plugin-development, maven-mojo

I have developed a custom Maven plugin and it has two Mojos. I debug it from my IDE and with one of goals it works well however it can not find the other one. It says:

```
 Unable to find the mojo 'replace' (or one of its required components)
```

Here are my mojos:

Working one:

```
/**
 * Goal for process
 *
 * @goal process
 * @phase compile
 *
 * @threadSafe
 */
public class ProcessMojo extends AbstractMojo {
```

Not working:

```
/**
 * Goal for replace
 *
 * @goal replace
 * @phase compile
 *
 * @threadSafe
 */
public class ReplaceMojo extends AbstractMojo {
```

What can be the reason, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was probably because of something within my mojo, I have recoded it and problem is fixed.